# mysql fetch data between two unix timestamps

Tags: mysql, between

I want to use the following query with Wilson Score Confidence as taken from [how to not sort by average rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) to calculate the relevant content based on votes in the last 24 hours from the time user searches. I have unix timestamps stored in a field but its not `datetime` type.

Now the query is:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.post, p.upvotes, p.downvotes, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 
 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes) / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) /
         (upvotes + downvotes)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) 
   AS ci_lower_bound FROM posts p WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 
   ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

I need to fetch top content posted in the last 24 hours. I know i need to put an additional `WHERE` condition using `BETWEEN` but not sure how?

Please help.

**UPDATE** Based on the answer below and some tweaking i made something like this:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.post, p.upvotes, p.downvotes, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes)
 / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) / (upvotes + downvotes))
 / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS ci_lower_bound 
 FROM posts p WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 
 AND p.unix_timestamp BETWEEN 1363023402 AND 1363109802 ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
```

The first value i calculated by subtracting 86400 seconds(i.e. 24 hours) from the current timestamp and got results. Please, if you think if its still can be improved, suggest me.

Comment: You would need the timestamp of each vote. Is that in your db somewhere?

Comment: @MartyMcVry Yes it is. it is stored in another table called `rating` with timestamps, post id and a flag of the type of vote, i.e. 1 for upvote and 2 for downvote. But i was thinking i should sort it according to the time the post was posted and not the votes. Am i wrong?

Comment: @MartyMcVry Ok, let me rephrase it, i want top content based on the votes(meaning, the most popular ones) in the last 24 hours. now considering this, what do you think i should do? Can u provide some sample code, maybe edit my query if its not too much to ask?

Comment: No, you're right... Didn't read your question through properly... You also wanted the posts to be from within the last 24 hours, so that solves the problem.

Comment: @MartyMcVry Can u see the updated query and tell if i am using it correctly?

Comment: Your query is correct. Would be indeed easier to calculate the timestamp outside of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *, complex_formula
FROM    posts
WHERE   upvotes + downvotes > 0
        AND ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP($user_time - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP($user_time)
```

Comment: `NOW()` would be server's current time. what if it is located in a different timezone than the user? i would like to use the unix timestamp taken from the user's computer or maybe the ip address. Can you please edit to show how can i use a real timestamp in place of `NOW()`

Comment: @coder101: taking relativity our of consideration, `NOW()` would mean "now" regardless of the time zone. But here you are, see the post update.

Comment: what exactly is ts? I guess it will be a new field created to facilitate sorting based on time and should not be my timestamp field's name?

Comment: @MartyMcVry and Quassnoi its giving an empty result when i put the timestamp in place of `NOW()`.the query i am using now is `SELECT p.id, p.post, p.upvotes, p.downvotes, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 
 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes) / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) /
         (upvotes + downvotes)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) 
   AS ci_lower_bound FROM posts p WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 AND p.unix_timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1363109802 - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1363109802)
   ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC`

Comment: i think instead of function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, `FROM_UNIXTIME` be used. am i right?

Comment: Your `unix_timestamp` field should be int, not varchar (just to be clear). `FROM_UNIXTIME` is only used to convert a timestamp into an actual date, which you don't need because you use a timestamp.

Comment: @MartyMcVry well, it is a varchar. but i use it only because while storing values when using INT, it was failing somewhow

Comment: @MartyMcVry Even after changing the type to INT, the above query still gives an empty result. what is the possibility?

Comment: @MartyMcVry Also, i just used EXPLAIN for the query and in the Extra column its says, `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`. Does that mean something to you?

Comment: @coder101: please post your table definition, some sample data and desired resultset.

Comment: how do i put up all these things in the question? or is there any website where i can put up the sql part

Comment: hi, i've put sample code here [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56c63/1). Please check and let me know

Comment: @MartyMcVry Could you also check my code on the link i just provided. i really need help here.

Comment: hi, i updated the question with the a lil tweaked version of your query. Do u think its right?